# Why does the FLEX 4 LineChart Legend stop displaying colors when LineSeries's lineStroke attribute changes?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flash-builder, linechart

I am implementing a LineChart in FLEX 4. I have the chart working well except I do not like the default colors and cannot use them, as they do not relate to my data very well. For instance, Orange is not a great default color for my data column "Outdoor temperature". I would rather override it and use a green color if possible.

When I explicitly specify the SolidColorStroke, like so, this breaks the LineChart Legend:

```
<mx:SolidColorStroke id = "s1" color="haloGreen" weight="2"/>
<mx:LineSeries yField="v1" form="curve" displayName="Indoor Temp" lineStroke="{s1}"/>
```

^ With this code, The LineChart Legend stops displaying the color for that specific LineSeries, and only displays in black.

**How can I override the LineSeries stroke color and persist those colors to the Legend's display?**

Is this a FLEX 4 bug? I noticed in FLEX 3 examples (even on Adobe's FLEX 3 Help website) you can override the stroke colors and it persists to the Chart Legend.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently (from what I can gather), this is a known bug in FLEX 4, and apparently Adobe is working on fixing this in their next release. Lame, I know.

To fix this, you must use the deprecated "Stroke" object, which produces compiler warnings in FLEX 4.